# Find k shortest paths with graph-tool

Tags: python-2.7, graph, networkx, graph-tool

I have a directed graph for which I am trying to find the top k shortest paths. At the moment I have implemented the network in graph-tool which provides a shortest path algorithm but no k shortest paths algorithm by what I can tell. I have come across this post ([All shortest paths using graph_tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743694/all-shortest-paths-using-graph-tool)) but I am not after all paths connecting two nodes.

It seems as if NetworkX has a function implemented for this (https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html?highlight=all_shortest_paths). Is there a way to somehow do this in graph-tool too or am I better off switching toolboxes and using NetworkX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available in the git version: https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/dev/topology.html#graph_tool.topology.all_shortest_paths

Comment: Thank you. Is the version stable? If not, am I able to install it without overwriting version 1.12? How do I go about installing it? Do I simply download it from git and then follow the compile instructions for v1.12? I am still slightly new to Linux so please excuse the many questions.

Comment: It is available now in the current stable version.

Comment: @TiagoPeixoto does this return the "k-shortest paths" (as asked by the OP; e.g., via Yen's algorithm) or only all shortest paths (same distance)?